# WillPopScope is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use PopScope instead. Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am getting this warning. I have read the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back). But my code is returning the true, or false value on some condition. How can I migrate this?

```
WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async {
              if (_actionIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                return true;
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  _actionIcon = const Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  );
                  _appBarTitle = Text('Heading',
                  _managePayrollBloc.add(_getSearch(""));
                });
                return false;
              }
            },
            child: SomeChild()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new variable

```
 bool didPop = true;
```

and then assigned this to canPop. This value is updated in the if condition.

```
PopScope(
            canPop: didPop,
            onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
              if (_actionIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                didPop = true;
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  _actionIcon = const Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  );
                  _appBarTitle = Text(LocaleKeys.payroll.tr(),
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white));
                });
                didPop = false;
              }
            },
            child:SomeChild()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace that like this:

```
PopScope(
  canPop: _myPopDisableEnableLogic(), // set it true according your app logic - your 1st if condition can be inside this (_actionIcon.icon == Icons.search return true

  onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
    // put only else condition part of your code here without returning anything
  },
)
```

Comment: Do I need to write a new condition for canPop? When I put my code in onPopInvoked it gives error on return "The return type 'bool' isn't a 'Future<void>', as required by the closure's context"

Comment: Yes, as you already set canPop value and your code will only run if bool equal to true. You need to update your function as bool can not be returned any more. It should be just functional code there. I'm updating the answer to reflect it clearly.